# Javascript: button/click counter integrated in function

Tags: javascript, html, function, loops

I would like to count the clicks or number of printed randomvalues on my website.

```js
var count = 0;
var button = document.getElementById("spin-button");
var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");

button.onclick = function(){
    count++;
    display.innerHTML = count;
}
```

```html
<p>The SPIN-button was pressed <span id="displayCount">0</span> times.</p>
```

The problem is, that my JS-program stops one part/function. Either I can set new random-values or I can count how often the button to calculate new values was pressed. It depends of the position of button.onClick, if it's out or inside the brackets. But both together doesn't work.

```js
function randomClickX() {

    var randomX1 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 );
    var randomX2 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 );
    var randomX3 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 );

    document.getElementById("randomX1").innerHTML = randomX1;
    document.getElementById("randomX2").innerHTML = randomX2;
    document.getElementById("randomX3").innerHTML = randomX3;

    var ausgabe = "Play again";
    if (randomX1 === randomX2) {
    if(randomX2 === randomX3) {
        var ausgabe = "Jackpot";
        }
    }

    var count = 0;
    var button = document.getElementById("spin-button");
    var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");


    button.onclick = function(){
        count++;
        display.innerHTML = count;
    }
}
```

button.onclick works in fact, but doesn't get along the randomClickX-function.

Where should I position it to do both?

Comment: Do you want the random numbers to update when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <p id="randomX1">X</p>
    <p id="randomX2">X</p>
    <p id="randomX3">X</p>
    <p id="msg"></p>
    <button type="button" name="button" id="spin-button">SPIN</button>
    <p>The SPIN-button was pressed <span id="displayCount">0</span> times.</p>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var count = 0;
    var button = document.getElementById("spin-button");
    var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");

    button.onclick = function(){
        count++;
        display.innerHTML = count;
        randomClickX();
    }

    function randomClickX() {

        var randomX1 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 );
        var randomX2 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 );
        var randomX3 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 );

        document.getElementById("randomX1").innerHTML = randomX1;
        document.getElementById("randomX2").innerHTML = randomX2;
        document.getElementById("randomX3").innerHTML = randomX3;
        var msg = document.getElementById("msg");

        var ausgabe = "Play again";
        if (randomX1 === randomX2) {
            if(randomX2 === randomX3) {
                var ausgabe = "Jackpot";
            }
        }
        msg.innerHTML = ausgabe;
    }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works as I wish to.
Could you explain _msg_? Why do I need this?

Comment: You don't need it I just used it to display "Play again" or "Jackpot" (default is "Play again" but if all three random values are same it change to "Jackpot").  You can use some other element to show ausgabe or you will perform some other function. That part is up to you. If you can check answer as right it would be really helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `randomClickX()`  is called when `spin-button` is clicked (or supposed to be). Based on that I'd write the code like so:

```js
//set up variables
var count = 0;
var button = document.getElementById("spin-button");
var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");

//when button is pressed. run code
button.onclick = function(){
    count++; //add to the total
    randomClickX() //spin the wheel
    display.innerHTML = count; //show the total spin count
}

function randomClickX() {
    //generate the random numbers
    var randomX1 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 );
    var randomX2 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 );
    var randomX3 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 );
    //display the random numbers
    document.getElementById("randomX1").innerHTML = randomX1;
    document.getElementById("randomX2").innerHTML = randomX2;
    document.getElementById("randomX3").innerHTML = randomX3;
    //if all 3 are the same assign ausgabe to "Jackpot"
    var ausgabe = "Play again";
    if (randomX1 === randomX2) {
    if(randomX2 === randomX3) {
        ausgabe = "Jackpot";
        }
    }
}
```

Note:

`ausgabe` is a dead variable. if you want it displayed have `randomClickX()` return `ausgabe` and when you call `randomClickX()` assign its result to where you want it to display. e.g. `winning.innerHTML = randomClickX()`

Comment: I tried this some hours before - didn't/doensn't work.
Why do you include _randomClickX()_ into the _button.onclick_-function?